# Hiring Problem - Approach Visualization Issue?

Tags: data-structures

I was reading about Secretary Problem over here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem

I am having doubt about its validity because of the approach i did take to prove it with coding.

The problem tells that the best suited candidate would most probably be found in 1/e i.e in 37% of the first candidates according to probabilistic analysis.

I tried to visualize this with code (JAVA). What I tried is following :-

1. Have rankings of candidates in a test randomly filled in a list.
2. Find the position of ranking 1. This would mean the percentage of candidates required for that particular test needed for best candidate is the position of best ranking 1.
3. Run some such iterations.
4. Average out the best candidate position calculated for iterations.

```java
package com.pravesh.designpattern.creational;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class HiringProblem {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random rd = new Random();
        int numberOfCandidates = 1000;
        int numberOfTests = 10000;

        List<Double> bestCandidatePositionPositionPercentages = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int testNumber = 0; testNumber < numberOfTests; testNumber++) {

            // Generate a random array of candidates with their rankings
            List<Integer> candidateRankings = new ArrayList<>();
            int candidateRanking = 0;
            while (candidateRanking < numberOfCandidates) {
                int random = rd.nextInt(numberOfCandidates + 1);
                if (!candidateRankings.contains(Integer.valueOf(random)) && random > 0
                        && random <= numberOfCandidates) {
                    candidateRanking++;
                    candidateRankings.add(Integer.valueOf(random));
                }
            }

            // Index starts from 0 and hence position+1
            int bestCandidatePosition = candidateRankings.indexOf(1) + 1;

            double bestCandidatePositionPercentage = (((double) bestCandidatePosition) / numberOfCandidates) * 100;

            bestCandidatePositionPositionPercentages.add(bestCandidatePositionPercentage);

        }

        double averagedBestPositionsPercentage = bestCandidatePositionPositionPercentages.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.summingDouble(n -> n)) / bestCandidatePositionPositionPercentages.size();

        System.out.println((int) averagedBestPositionsPercentage);

    }

}
```

I was expecting a average value of 37% but it comes in range 45-53 each time when i ran the program most of the time.

Could anybody let me know if the approach is lacking something.

Comment: You've not understood the problem. "The problem tells that the best suited candidate would most probably be found in 1/e i.e in 37% of the first candidates" - This is not what the problem states. "I am having doubt about its validity" - Luckilly I am not ;)

Comment: Re read the wiki page, especially this part https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem#Deriving_the_optimal_policy

Comment: Your code is basically saying - If I randomly pick a value between 0 and 99 and do this over and over what will the average value be? And the answer is 49.5